# Using a function as an object property

Tags: javascript, function, object, properties

I am studying JavaScript and I am trying to produce an object with a property that is a function. However, when logging character.strength in the console I just get the function without being executed. What would be the correct syntax?

```
name: "Jack",
age: 19,

strength: function() {
        character.name.length() + name.age;
    }
};

console.log(character.strength);
```

Comment: Please show your whole code including the line `var character = {`…

Comment: `.length` is not a method that you can call, but a number!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *call* the function:

```
console.log(character.strength());
```

You can also implement a *getter* property:

```
{ get strength() { return this.name.length.toString() + this.age; } }
```

...and access the value as you did in your code sample:

```
console.log(character.strength);
```

Anyway, note that you've an issue in your code. It's not `character.name.length()`. `length` is a `String` object property, thus you need to access it without parenthesis (`character.name.length`)!

And, also, you're not accessing `name` and `age` properties of your object... you need to reference object properties with `this` keyword within the functions or properties of some given object.